# Class '\Omnipay\YooKassa\Gateway' not found

Tags: php, laravel, omnipay

i have added LIB yookassa to laravel/vendor/omnipay/yookassa, but after call

```php
$gateway = Omnipay::create('YooKassa');
```

it was error Class '\Omnipay\YooKassa\Gateway' not found

The main composer.json (require section)

```json
    "omnipay/paypal": "*",
    "omnipay/stripe": "*",
    "omnipay/yookassa": "*",
    "yoomoney/yookassa-sdk-php": "^2.4",
    "hiqdev/omnipay-yandex-kassa": "^3.0",
    "igor-tv/omnipay-yookassa": "^4.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first clear the cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

after you need

```
composer install
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i done it, but composer wirh errrors  `
-bash-4.2$ composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In PackageManifest.php line 122:
                         
  Undefined index: name  
                         
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
-bash-4.2$ 
`

Comment: and i can not work with composer correct, because it say alredy this errors: -bash-4.2$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
                                                      
In CurlDownloader.php line 645:
                                                                                                               
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/wiledia/themes" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 ):                
  {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"}

Comment: Can you remove your composer.lock and install it again. Automativally it will generate a new composer.lock